# Why ascensor.js plugin doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, navigation

I'm using the plugin [ascensor.js](http://kirkas.ch/ascensor/) and I'm trying to do a simple example, but it doesn't works, and I can't see the error.

The code is in the following fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/C2vLH/2/**

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ascensorBuilding').ascensor({
        ascensorName: 'ascensor',
        childType: 'section',
        ascensorFloorName: ['hello1', 'hello2', 'hello3', 'hello4'],
        time: 1000,
        windowsOn: 1,
        direction: "chocolate",
        ascensorMap: [
            [1, 0],
            [1, 1],
            [2, 1]
        ],
        easing: 'easeInOutQuad',
        keyNavigation: true,
        queued: false,
        queuedDirection: "y",
        overflow: "hidden"
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<button class="ascensor ascensorLink0">hello1</button>
<button class="ascensor ascensorLink1">hello2</button>
<button class="ascensor ascensorLink2">hello3</button>
<button class="ascensor ascensorLink3">hello4</button>

<div id="ascensorBuilding">
    <section>Hello1</section>
    <section>Hello2</section>
    <section>Hello3</section>
    <section>Hello4</section>
</div>
```

---

In the result I see all the sections in the same page, and when I click the buttons doesn't happens anything...

Do you know any plugin which does a similar effect?

Any tip or advice would be appreciated. if you need more info, let me know and I'll edit the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple problems and they are not simple (unless the version of the ascensor script is outdated).   The first issue is fairly simple, and illustrates the initial problem - some of the documentation doesn't match the code.  In particular, the case doesn't match.

For example, you have `childType: 'section'` (lowercase c) but you need `ChildType: 'section'` uppercase C.  This is true of all the settings.

After fixing this the fun begins!  The various arrays you specified follow the documentation, but the ascensor script in the jsfiddle is attempting to parse strings. `"hello1 | hello2 |..."` versus `['hello1', 'hello2'...]` (similar issue for the AscensorMap).  Perhaps the ascensor script reference refers to an outdated version, or the plug-in has changed and the docs haven't been updated.

Comment: Hellyeah! that's it, the version of github is working perfect: https://github.com/kirkas/Ascensor.js Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/C2vLH/14/

Answer (score 0):

The reverse of the current answer is now true.

Using the latest version of Ascensor (1.8.0 (2014-02-23)), you have to specify the property names in lower case.

e.g. change `ChildType: 'section'` to `childType: 'section'`.

The examples all around the net are unfortunately using older versions.